# Relationship between aperture function and Fraunhofer diffraction patern

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, diffraction

I have read that the Fraunhofer diffraction pattern of a source is the Fourier transform of the aperture, however I have not been able to follow the proofs. All of them seem to demonstrate that the two are proportional to each other as with [this derivation](http://www.thefouriertransform.com/applications/diffraction2.php) which concludes that

$$E(Z)=C\mathfrak{F}[A(X)]$$

where $E(Z)$ is the wave in the far field, $C$ is a constant and $\mathfrak F[A(X)]$ is the Fourier transform of the aperture function.

Am I just misunderstanding what people mean when they say the two are equal, or is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Why might you expect that the diffraction is _not_ directly related to the Fourier transform of the aperture (assuming the wave hitting the aperture is vaguely like a plane wave)?

Comment: In your formula the left side is a function of Z and the right side a function of X--which is wrong.  Both sides should be a function of the angle between the perpendicular to the aperture and the angle of the incoming/outgoing plane wave, i.e. the off axis angle.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I just misunderstanding what people mean when they say the two are equal

It seems so. When people say that the two are equal, they mean that they are equal modulo trivial factors of proportionality. Generally, in physics, we tend to set very little stock on trivial constants.